# OrientDB Studio access via Nginx gives blank page

Tags: nginx, orientdb, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

Trying to run OrientDB on an AWS EC2 instance inside a VPC within a private subnet.
Another EC2 server is in a public DMZ, running nginx with follow config.

```
server
{
listen 443 ssl;
server_name server-name.com;

ssl_certificate     server-name.crt;
ssl_certificate_key server-name.key;

location /
    {
    proxy_pass http://172.16.2.1:2480/;
    }
}
```

I'm struggling to access OrientDB Studio from the outside world.

When I put https://server-name.com into a browser (safari, chrome & firefox) I just get a blank page - not a timeout.

Using the web inspector it appears nothing has been received by the browser.

**curl** gives the following so OrientDB might be sending a response.

```
$ curl https://server-name.com
<!--
    ~ /*
    ~  *  Copyright 2014 Orient Technologies LTD (info(at)orientechnologies.com)
    ...
    ...
    ~  * For more information: http://www.orientechnologies.com
    ~  */
    -->

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Redirecting to OrientDB Studio...</title>
 <meta name="title" content="Document | DBMS | Database | Java | Studio" />
 <meta name="description" content="OrientDB Studio" />
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/studio/index.html">
 <style type="text/css">
 body {
     font-size: 9pt;
     font-family: Arial;
 }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>Redirecting to OrientDB Studio...
 </body>
$
```

Just see a blank page with a browser.

Answer (score 2):

Well I found and fixed the issue.

Both my desktop and laptop have adguard installed to save me from advertising. Adguard decided the response from OrientDB Studio is either an ad or some other traffic I should be protected from.

Nothing was getting to the browser....
Kicking myself

Fix was to disable Adguard.